# CLI script with python with variable including special character

Tags: python, unicode, command-line-interface, ogr2ogr

I am trying to run a CLI script with python but I am running into issues due to special characters. 
So if I run this harcoded it work just fine.
Writing the "Innjsø" layer to database named as "innsjo" for the table name.

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=postgres  password=postgres "C:\path\GML.gml" Innsjø -nln innsjo
```

However I try to run this programmatically I run into problem with the special characters.

```
command = [
        "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 2.18\\bin\\ogr2ogr.exe",
        "-f",
        "PostgreSQL",
        "PG:host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres
        loadfile,
        gml_layer_name,
        "-nln", set_table_name
    ]

subprocess.check_call(command)
```

If the variable layer_name includes special characters i get this error. Layers only using latin characters work just fine.

```
ERROR 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer 'Innsj°'!
```

I have no control of what the layers in the GML file are called. How can I run CLI script with python with names including special characters?

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3? And what returns `chcp` from the command line?

Comment: It is Python3 I am using. chcp return Active code page: 850

Comment: I currently have no narrow char CLI application on my system, so only posting it as a comment. You could try to use `subprocess.check_call(command, encoding='cp850')`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it, but unfortunately it did nothing. 
I am not sure where the error lay. I tried to set the terminal to UTF-8 by typing `chcp 65001` When I did it the `°` in `Innsj°` got removed just showing `Innsj`. So I am mostly playing around with what I can fid. Like trying to change encoding `gml_layer_names.encode('cp850', 'strict').decode('cp850', 'strict')`

Answer (score 1):

I could partially reproduce with a tiny C program dumping the code points of its parameters <sup>(*)</sup>. What happens is that Python 3 on Windows is a fully unicode enabled program, and because of that `subprocess` uses under the hood `CreateProcessW` and passes the command line with wide characters. So when the child program uses narrow chars, Windows convert the wide characters to the default ANSI code page which is CP1252 for West European Languages.

Specifically, it appears that the console codepage is not used.

Because of that, the most reliable way is to use the 1252 code page in the console: `chcp 1252`.

The problem is that if your layer names were stored as cp850 byte strings, you will now have wrong values for all non ASCII characters.

In that case a possible workaround is to encode the string as `cp850` and decode it as `cp1252`. That way, when the system library will encode it as `cp1252` you will get the expected cp850 value.

It will work here, because `'ø'.encode('cp850').decode('cp1252')` exists (it is the character U+203A `›` SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK). So this should work:

```
command = [
        "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 2.18\\bin\\ogr2ogr.exe",
        "-f",
        "PostgreSQL",
        "PG:host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres
        loadfile,
        gml_layer_name.encode('cp850').decode('cp1252'),
        "-nln", set_table_name
    ]

subprocess.check_call(command)
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> For references, here is the C code used to dump the codepoints of the command line parameters:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        _tprintf(_T(">%s< "), argv[i]);

        for (TCHAR *c = argv[i]; *c != 0; c++) {
            _tprintf(_T("%02x "), (unsigned)(_TUCHAR)*c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that insight, that's really usefull to know!
Possible there is something else going on becuase unfortunately it still did not work -_- However when i used `gml_layer_names.encode('cp1252', 'strict').decode('cp1252', 'strict')` with chcp `1252` is displayed the "ø" correctly but failed for anther reason not clear to me. `ERROR 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer 'Innsjø'!` So might have to resort and try something lese

Comment: Actually, I more or less by chance used this `gml_layer_names.encode('UTF-8', 'strict').decode('1252', 'strict'),`  With chcp 1252 and that actually did the trick!
On top of  my py file i use # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- not sure if that is required in python3 but this seem to solve my problem :)
Thanks for your help on this!